# Renaming files in bulk, depending on the subfolder they are in

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, file-rename, bulk, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files in a bunch of subfolders.
I want them to have a 'prefix', that coresponds with the subfolder they are placed in.

Example:

- Main folder:

  - Subfolder1
  - Subfolder2
  - Subfolder3

All the files in Subfolder1, should be renamed to "Subfolder1_filename.pdf", and the same for the rest of the folders.

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\user\desktop\testfolder\'

foreach ($i in $dir){
    $foldername = Get-ChildItem $dir -name
    cd $newdir
    rename-item -NewName  {$foldername + "_" + $_.Name}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse -File

ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    $FolderName = ((Split-Path -Path $File.FullName -Parent) -split '\\')[-1]
    $FileName = $File.Name
    Rename-Item -Path $File.FullName -NewName "${FolderName}_$FileName"
}
```

This will accomplish renaming them according to their container, but you would need to utilize `Move-Item` if you want to move+rename, or something of that nature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I get this error message, as i try your code.


Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\user\desktop\testfolder\ps.ps1:16 char:22
+     Rename-Item -Path <<<<  $File.FullName -NewName "${FolderName}_$FileName"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBinding
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M
   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Did you capture the files with `Get-ChildItem` @user1851594 ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it captures the files. I tried narrowing the code down, just to check:

`$dir = 'C:\Users\BIT\Desktop\QGIS_LEG\test\'

$Files = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -file
return $files`

Comment: This is what i got, when i removed the "-file" from the $files.  https://imgur.com/a/7JGz2

Comment: @user1851594 what's there with the `-File` switch?  Are you on PSv2?

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks a lot for the help!